# Obtain URL from Android Market Application

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-play

I was wondering if it's possible to obtain the URL from Android Market applications.
For example, I'd like to to know the URL of the Facebook application on Android market, the result I'd like to have is something like this.

```
http://android-es.com/repo/apk/social/facebook.apk
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a link that will open the Market page for the app when clicked on a phone with:

```
market://search?q=pname:<package-name-here>
```

in the case of facebook the package name is com.facebook.katana...so:

```
market://search?q=pname:com.facebook.katana
```

should do it :]

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible. The only way to get a market released apk is to go to the Market or get it off your phone. There's no way to link to it.

Comment: And what about using android emulator with Android market and monitoring all the internet activity with wireshark?  I guess that at least in one point the mobile phone should connect to the URL place where the apk is connected right?

Comment: It uses a Push Notification over the GTalk service to install apps. What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

```
market://details?id=package-name
```

This will take you to the detail page.
Saves another touch at the search result.